# When placing InDesign 5 file A into Indesign file B, the hyperlinks from file A no longer work

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, adobe-indesign

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere...

So, I am trying to create a low-maintenance system for a thank you PDF file I routinely email to clients. I want all of the PDFs to have the same footer information, with links to my social media. So, I created a footer document that just had the images and links at the bottom. Then, I placed this into the several variations I have on this thank you letter.

Problem is, when I export as a PDF, there aren't any links. Yes, the include hyperlinks box is checked. When I export just the footer, the links work fine. If I place the footer as a PDF with hyperlinks into the thank you file, and then export that, no links. I can't figure out how to get the main file to pull through the hyperlinks in the placed file...

Comment: Can you share your file which you placing in indesign, so that can go through that file and ill also check for you! :}

Comment: You are doing it correctly. Hyperlinks don't carry over from within placed PDFs -- it seems like this is exactly the same issue. Post on [Adobe InDesign Feature Request/Bug Report](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform); very conveniently you can opt to call it "a bug" or "a feature request" in the same form.